# How to make the table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to make the data available in table format but the table head and row appear as two different body, how do i work with that

```
  $("#container").html("<table> <th>Name</th> <th>Address</th> <th>Sex</th> <th>Email</th>")
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<tr><td>" +
            data[i].name + "</td><td>" +
            data[i].address + "</td><td>" +
            data[i].sex + "</td><td>" +
            data[i].email + "</td><tr>"
          );
        }
        $("container").append("</table>")
```

This is what I get

[image]

I want the whole table, not two seperate buddies.

Comment: can you add a fiddle with the problem? and what do you expect ?

Comment: I don't know how to add asp.net project to fiddle.

Comment: Perhaps, close the `tr` tag here -> `data[i].email + "</td><tr>"`

Comment: Try this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/827nuhxv/1/, you can replace "Jack" with your values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var htmlTable = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Adress</th><th>Sex</th>   <th>Email</th></tr>'; 
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlTable += '<tr><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].adress + '</td><td>' + data[i].sex + '</td><td>' + data[i].email + '</td></tr>';
}
htmlTable += '</table>';

$('#container').html(htmlTable);
```

Add the table to the DOM at once, otherwise the browser will have problems rendering it.

Comment: This is good, but don't forget about `var` (`i = 0` will become global).

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget about that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't append `<table>` and `</table>` separately, appending DOM elements (by setting `innerHTML` behind the scene) is not the same as string concatenation. Browser detects invalid markup and fixes it accordingly by adding missing parts of the table. So as the result you get one table after first append, and in the loop you are appending rows into `#container`, not the table, which is rendered incorrectly.

To fix try something like this:

```
var $table = $("#container").html("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Sex</th><th>Email</th></tr></table>");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $table.append("<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].address + "</td><td>" + data[i].sex + "</td><td>" + data[i].email + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Note, I also cached `$table` variable so you don't query DOM in each iteration.

Also pay attention to closing tags, in your code you have couple of problems like `<tr>` where it should be `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<tr>` too for `<th>`:

```
$("#container").html("<table> <tr><th>Name</th> <th>Address</th> <th>Sex</th> <th>Email</th></tr></table>")
```

Comment: Good catch - missing `tr`, this is another problem too.

Comment: You still have an unclosed `<table>`. The end result will be exactly the same.

Comment: ...and closing the table here won't help anything because the rows added later won't be inside it. jQuery *already* implicitly adds the end tag there. The end result is *still* exactly the same.